# Why is Async.RunSynchronously hanging?

Tags: f#

In my f# project, I'm calling a c# library that returns me a Task. When I try to do this in my f# project, nothing happens.

```
let str = getName() |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

However, if I update my code to use an async workfolow, it doesn't hang anymore. What am I doing wrong when calling Async.RunSynchronously?

```
async {
     let! str = getName() |> Async.AwaitTask
     //Do something with str
}
```

Comment: What is `getName`? How is it defined?

Comment: it doesn't hang because in second snippet you don't do anything. `async` is lazy. And in first snippet you hang because `getName()` blocks and doesn't return.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example you just **build** `async` workflow, but **don't** actually **run** it.

It is designed that way so you could define a complex workflow without running every async part of it immediately, but instead run the whole thing when it's good and ready.

In order to run it you need to call `Async.RunSynchronously` or `Async.StartAsTask`:

```
async {
 let! str = getName() |> Async.AwaitTask
 //Do something with str
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Also, if you **do** need to work with `Task`s, it's probably better to use [TaskBuilder.fs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskBuilder.fs/) instead of `Async`.